# Change GridView Column Value in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which has one column Status, which has default value False(in a label) in each Row. 
There is one Column named as Student, this is link button. So when User clicks on Student name
a gridview opens for to display data for that User. I change data for second GridView and then save it. So When this data is successfully saved. I want to modify the Status of 1st GridView from False to True for that particular row.
So please suggest me how to do it?
Is it necessary to bind the GridView again. IS there any easy method, please let me know.

So the main problem is how to modify a particular cell value in a GridView, based on some some action.

I'm writing the piece of Code, which I'm trying.
I 'm saving the Parent GridView Row no. is ViewState.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["RowIndexPOS"] != null)
    {
        int iRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RowIndexPOS"]);
        Label lblStatus = (Label)GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.Rows[iRowIndex].FindControl("LabelStatusPendingPOSId");
        //Means all rows in GridView are successfully associated
        if (table.Rows.Count == iResultCount)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Associated";
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Pending";
        }
    }
}
```

Code to bind first gridview

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = null;
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Row Number", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("POS Id", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Action", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Status", typeof(string)));
for (int index = 0; index < m_listStrPendingListOfPOS.Count; index++)
{
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    int iRowNo = index + 1;
    dr["Row Number"] = iRowNo;
    string strGridViewPOSId = m_listStrPendingListOfPOS[index];
    dr["POS Id"] = strGridViewPOSId;
    dr["Action"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Status"] = "Pending";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);                                            
}

ViewState["POSTable"] = dt;
GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.DataSource = dt;
GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.DataBind();
```

When I'm trying this. Status column is Empty in each Row. After setting this to Associated.

Comment: If the parent gridview is accessible from the save function of the second gridview, then with student id or the row number info of the parent, you will be able to change the value of the status.

Comment: Parent GridView is not accessible. But I have the row no. info.

Comment: there are many ways to do it. If the parent is bound to a datasource and if that is accessible in save func, you can effect the change. Or if parent is bound to database you can change and reload. Without giving the complete scenario it is hard to comment.

Comment: Parent is bound to dataset.

Comment: Is there any error for the above function? It will be good to check if lblStatus is not null before you actually change its value.

Comment: Its not null , not giving any exception or error.

Comment: Try to check the onLoad function is implementing the isPostBack flag. You can set the value change in the dataset and reload also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above scenario what I could infer is that when you make changes in the second grid view (which shows the student info) and save it successfully, then value of Label column 'Status' in the parent grid view should be modified to 'True'.

Possible fixes:

1. Since the column 'Status' is not a bound field and it is
   being set depending on the condition you should set this value each
   and every time when the gridview is loaded. So you can do this either
   in page_load function or in Grid View Load function as the grid view
   will not know that this value has been modified earlier unless you
   set this value manually.
2. Instead you can also change the field 'Status' as bound so that you
   could retrieve or modify the value in the dataset (as you use it here) and can always
   have the updated value shown in the gridview 'Status' column without
   doing it manually.

Note: I could help you with the code for the same if you could post some more code on what is happening.

Solution Part2:

Try the below:

Let us suppose you have put the 'Code to bind first gridview' in the method `bindTheGriView()`. With this assumption the below code could work fine. Please modify it according to your code.

btnSave_Click method:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool statusFlag=false;
    if (ViewState["RowIndexPOS"] != null)
    {
        int iRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RowIndexPOS"]);
        Label lblStatus = (Label)GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.Rows[iRowIndex].FindControl("LabelStatusPendingPOSId");
        //Means all rows in GridView are successfully associated
        if (table.Rows.Count == iResultCount)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Associated";
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Pending";
        }
    }
    //now call the binding method with the bool flag value
     bindTheGriView();
}
```

Your method that has the 'Code to bind first gridview' (bindTheGriView(bool statusFlag) in this sample) will look like:

```
private void bindTheGriView()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = null;
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Row Number", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("POS Id", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Action", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Status", typeof(string)));
            for (int index = 0; index < m_listStrPendingListOfPOS.Count; index++)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                int iRowNo = index + 1;
                dr["Row Number"] = iRowNo;
                string strGridViewPOSId = m_listStrPendingListOfPOS[index];
                dr["POS Id"] = strGridViewPOSId;
                dr["Action"] = string.Empty;
                //check for the flag. if the flag is true set status to Pending else to Associated
                dr["Status"]=((Label)GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.Rows[index].FindControl("LabelStatusPendingPOSId")).Text;
               dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            ViewState["POSTable"] = dt;
            GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.DataSource = dt;
            GridViewMultiplePOSAssociationId.DataBind();
        }
```

You should call this binding method each and every time you think the Status value has been modified since it is a dynamic data.

Also call the function bindTheGriView() in the Page_Load method

Comment: I have added the gridview binding function. 
Associated means True.
Pending means False.

Comment: check out the solution part of my answer and let me know if you have issues.

Comment: I have done as it U have told to do. 
Still the Status column value is not modified. 
Its still coming Pending instead of Associated.

Comment: I'm sorry I have made mistake. I totally forgot about the Page_Load function. Give me some time I will get back to you

Comment: @user3264676: can you try the one posted as Solution Part2 and let me know in case of issues

Comment: can you let me know what is 'm_listStrPendingListOfPOS'?

Comment: it list<string>, its basically no. of rows to be created on GridView.

Comment: I have few more questions. What is 'RowIndexPOS'; can you confirm if the correct row_index is being picked up in the method 'btnSave_Click()'; also can you post the aspx code too and what is the output you get the above code?

Comment: @user3264676: is this thread still active? if active please respond to the above query.!

Comment: What if I wanted the value of a column of a certain to be changed (replaced) but not saved back to the DB? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987766/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-column-of-a-gridview-based-on-another-column-value

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: can you describe more specific. the url is broken

Comment: @user3240361 I deleted the question because I accomplished using UpdatePanel and temporarily holding the value. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming that you are using BoundFields for the your Link Button columns and you want to handle the LinkButton-click event (instead of the e.g. RowCommand of the GridView):

```
protected void LinkClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //After Populating your Second Gridview
    var closeLink = (Control) sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) closeLink.NamingContainer;
    dataGridView1.Rows[rowNum].Cells[colNum].Text = "True"; 
}
```

Comment: Dear friend, You have understood the problem wrong. Please read it again.

Comment: Is your first Gridview Status Column depends on Second GridView Value ?? If it not depends on second gridview as written in description then try to use this code it will work.

Comment: I dont want to change the status when I click on LinkButton.  
Its When I click the Save button of second GridView.

Answer (score 0):

When you save the data of first gridview,on this occasion change the dataset for bind the 2nd gridview,you must load the 2nd gridview at the time of data save on 1st gridview,so no other option.